# how to index array after preg_match_all

Tags: multidimensional-array, preg-match-all

After doing following :
    `preg_match_all($pattern,$str,$anchor);`
If my next code line is :
    `echo count($anchor[2]);`
It gives me output : 50
But if my next code lines are
    `echo count($anchor[2]);
        $title = $anchor[2];`

It shows me error "Notice: Undefined offset: 2" for BOTH lines.
How can adding a line give error in previous line ??

Comment: I just removed lines `$anchor = array();$title = array();` preceding all other lines. And it seems (as of now) that above code has started working. Any ideas why such initialization of arrays was creating problems ?

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest using print_r($anchor); to find out what's in your array, it will show you everything in all of the indexes and you can quickly ascertain which index you need.